# React trying to make a list of dynamic inputs

Tags: reactjs, forms, list, input, dynamic

I have built this site 
https://supsurvey.herokuapp.com/surveycreate/
now I am trying to move the fronted to React so I can learn React in the process.

with vanila js it was much easier to create elements dynamically.
I just did createElement and after that when I clicked "submit" button
I loop throw all the elements of Options and take each target.value input.
so I loop only 1 time in the end when I click Submit and that's it I have now a list of all the inputs.

in react every change in each input field calls the "OnChange" method and bubbling the e.targe.value to the parent and in the parent I have to copy the current array of the options and rewrite it every change in every field.

is there other way? because it seems crazy to work like that.

Options.jsx

`````
```import React, { Component } from "react";

class Option extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { inputValue: "", index: props.index };
  }

  myChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value });
    this.props.onChange(this.state.index, event.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        className="survey-answer-group"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add Option..."
        onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Option;

______________________________________________________________________________
Options.jsx````

```import React, { Component } from "react";
import Option from "./option";

class Options extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return <div>{this.createOptions()}</div>;
  }

  createOptions = () => {
    let options = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < this.props.numOfOptions; index++) {
      options.push(
        <Option key={index} onChange={this.props.onChange} index={index} />
      );
    }
    return options;
  };
}

export default Options;```
______________________________________________________________________________

App.jsx

```import React from "react";

import OptionList from "./components/Options";
import AddButton from "./components/add-button";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    numOfOptions: 2,
    options: [{ id: 0, value: "" }, { id: 1, value: "" }]
  };

  handleChange = (index, value) => {
    const options = [...this.state.options];
    console.log("from App", value);

    options[index].value = value;
    this.setState({
      options: options
    });

    console.log(this.state);
  };

  addOption = () => {
    const options = [...this.state.options];
    options.push({ id: this.state.numOfOptions + 1, value: "" });

    this.setState({
      numOfOptions: this.state.numOfOptions + 1,
      options: options
    });
  };

  submitButton = () => {};

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="poll-create-grid">
        <div id="poll-create-options">
          <OptionList
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            numOfOptions={this.state.numOfOptions}
          />
        </div>
        <button
          className="surveyCreate-main-btn-group"
          onClick={this.addOption}
        >
          Add
        </button>
        <button
          className="surveyCreate-main-btn-group"
          onClick={this.submitButton}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```
`````

Comment: I found this online https://codesandbox.io/s/o54n9zwnly

what is a good practice?

Comment: Yea that's same thing you are trying to do but with React-hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So firstly, 
The issue is with the way your `OptionList` component is defined.

Would be nice to pass in the `options` from the state into the component rather than the number of options

```js
<OptionList
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   options={this.state.options}
/>
```

The you basically just render the options in the `OptionsList` component (I'm assuming it's same as the `Options` one here

```js
class Options extends Component {
...
  render() {
    return 
      (<div>{Array.isArray(this.props.options) && 
        this.props.options.map((option) => <Option 
          key={option.id}
          index={option.id}
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          value={option.value}
        />)}
      </div>);
  }
...
}
```

You would want to use the value in the `Option` component as well.

`this.props.onChange(this.state.index, event.target.value);` No need using the state here to be honest

`this.props.onChange(this.props.index, event.target.value);` is fine

Comment: what is the point passing  options={this.state.options} there isn't value inside of them, the value is only when a user is typing inside input, so the value is only created in thr "Question" child